# How to replace file inside JAR which is inside RAR in Maven EAR build

Tags: maven, packaging, ear, maven-ear-plugin

I'm trying to build an EAR that consist of some resource adapter (let's call it resource.rar) and some other JARs.
resource.rar contains several JARs:
 - resource-api.jar
 - resource-impl.jar
 - resource-ejb.jar
 - others...

What I need to do is to replace persistence.xml that is in the following path:
**my_application.ear/resource.rar/resource-ejb.jar/META-INF/persistence.xml**
with some filered resource.
My goal is to change properties like:

   `property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"`
         `property name="hibernate.dialect"`

maven-ear-plugin allows to unpack artifacts but as far as I know it is possible only for one level structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [TrueZip Maven plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/).